# Issues with UI layout in macOS 10.10, working on macOS 10.12

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, cocoa, autolayout

I've submitted my macOS app to App Store and it was rejected. They provided a screenshot and the layout was totally different from my development machine. I created the app using Xcode 9, on a MacBook Pro 13", late 2011, without retina screen, running MacOS 10.12. I asked them about their environment and they said they tested using MacOS 10.10.

I'm wondering why that is happening. I tested my app using Xcode, and also exporting it and running it directly. I didn't get any issue. Could that be something to do with auto layout?

My background is iOS, so maybe I'm forgetting something more intrinsic to the Cocoa platform.

This is the screen on Xcode, with auto layout constraints.
[image: 01]

This is the screen, running outside xcode.
[image: 02]

This is the screenshot sent by Apple in the review process
[image: 03]

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/265199#265199

I did some extra testing, using only this view hierarchy:

```
View  
    - Vertical StackView  
        - Horizontal StackView  
            - Custom View  
       - Button
```

Also I had the constraints:

Vertical StackView
- Center horizontally on screen
- Anchor/Margin to top

Custom View
- Fixed Height
- Fixed Width

This was suffiient to reproduce the issue.

From the debug code, I could see that the Custom View had correct size, Horizontal Stackview had correct size. Only the vertical didn't have the propersize. Looked like VerticalStackview was clipping its content.

I managed to get it working by:
1) Fixing height on Horizontal StackView with constraint
2) Changing hugging priority on Horizontal StackView
3) Change clipping resistance on Horizontal StackView

Seems that for some reason, on macOS 10.10, the stack views or auto layout is not working in the same manner. Seems the content is not being calculated in the same way. By forcing constraints in every child view I got it working.